# what is the best way to calculate the return in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation

I have a DataFrame as below

I want to get the standard deviation of stock returns `st.dev (T1/T0-1,T2/T1-1..etc)`

for example, `st.dev((9.5/36.5)-1,(6.125/9.5)-1...etc)`

The result will be added to DataFrame number 2.

Can u please suggest the best way to do it? Obviously, I need to do it to every stock. Can you please help?

Thanks in Advance!

P.S: you can ignore the standard deviation part, if you can just help me with the returns, I will do the rest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be clear, the result should ideally be added to the Return column. Thanks again guys!

Comment: for example, TSL returns will be 44.75 - 44?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `T1/T0-1` values with [df.pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html). From there you can use `.agg` to aggregate with several functions.

```
# sample df
# please always provide a sample that can be easily pasted and tested
# you could get it with `df.head(10).to_dict('split')`
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AAPL': [36.5, 9.5, 6.125, 40.25, 43.875, 40, 42.25],
    'TSL': [44, 43.625, 47.875, 64.25, 17.375, 14.124, 44.75],
    'GDXJ': [43.875, 13.625, 22.5, 37.125, 5.5, 21.125, 21.25],
    'DAL': [11.625, 33.25, 4.625, 36, 36.25, 14.875, 31.75]
})

df2 = df.pct_change().agg(['mean', 'std']).T
```

Output

```
          mean       std
AAPL  0.755739  2.379347
TSL   0.280437  0.992349
GDXJ  0.434482  1.340593
DAL   1.389140  2.838230
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works better than i expected. I had to make loops but i felt it is inefficient. I am happy I asked the question here. I will provide a better sample next time.
So basically, the .pct_change will get the return in the correct order (i.e T1/T0 and not the opposite). Very cool. Thanks again Richiev

Answer (score 0):

This is all it takes, i believe:

```
df.std(axis = 0, skipna = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a=[(df.iloc[i+1]/df.iloc[i])-1 for i in range(df.shape[0]-1)]
df1=pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(a).std(),columns=["Return"])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.